# Remove header columns in Page 5.0

Tags: pages, iwork

In the new iWork Pages, there is by default 3 cells or columns in the header and I cannot remove the column back to its original one column header just like the normal header in Pages 09'.

If you see that in the image, it is NOT a table, but the header when the cursor hover on it.

[image]

Comment: It's true. If you whichever column you want, the text will be visible when you print or create a PDF. So much for WYSIWYG. Now it's what you get is what you want but not what you see, WYGIWYWBNWYS Nice. I miss Steve Jobs. He would have fired somebody over this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact what Apple did here is better than before :

If you write in only one of these 3 columns it behaves as if there were only one column.

[image]

Comment: Not better, just stupid.

Comment: This a well argumented statement.

Answer (score 3):

When you go to print, "truncated" headers will appear in their entirety on the printed page. It's just a glitch in the editing environment.

Answer (score 2):

It helps to insert a text box in one of the cells. You can adjust its size, background, all styling and so on. The best thing is that this text box "overlaps" the header so it does not get truncated.

Comment: why is the "resize the cells to fit the stuff in them" not the default behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a header that spans more than one column, and choose to stage your headers  - i.e. a different header on different "chapters", then your headers are truncated only to the width of the "cell".

Answer (score 0):

The only "fix" I've seen that works is to copy an old '09 document and open it in v5.